# How to pass parameters to dll?

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary

I have this function in DLL:

```
CPPLIBRARY_API int fnCPPLibrary(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Main function:

```
int main(){
    FARPROC myCppProc;
    HINSTANCE hDll;
    DWORD L;
    int result;

    hDll = LoadLibrary("CPPLibrary");

    if (hDll != NULL){
        myCppProc = GetProcAddress(hDll, "fnCPPLibrary");

        if (myCppProc != NULL){
            result = myCppProc();
        cout <<"Result from library: " <<result;
        int a;
        }
    }
}
```

I can easly call fnCPPLibrary when it doesn't have arguments but how to pass params from program to that dll function? Is it simple or it requires some complicated code?

Comment: Did you try looking at the [documentation for GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? It has an example.

Comment: Just call it like any function that requires arguments.

Comment: @crashmstr, yes I read but I dont understand it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It throws error "Too many arguments to call"

Comment: @pawkondr the example is a bit vague, but you need to cast the function pointer to have the correct signature. But a simple [Google of "GetProcAddress Example"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=getprocaddress%20example) has other examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function pointer must have a signature that matches the function you're calling.

Not knowing what `CPPLIBRARY_API` is:

```
typedef int (*DLLFunc)(int, int);
DLLFunc myCppProc;
//...
myCppProc = (DLLFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "fnCPPLibrary");  // Cast to function pointer
myCppProc(1, 2);  // call function
```

I don't know what the qualifier CPPLIBRARY_API consists of, and it may be important (could be a calling convention -- you have to post this information).  But in general, this is how you declare a function pointer and use `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It worked, but it must be: 
DLLFunc myCppProc instead of:
DLLFunc myProc.
Thanks for help.