# How to retrieve array variable from DLL? (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

A 3rd party C library contains the following global variable and function:

```
typedef RtBasis float[4][4];

RI_EXPORT RtBasis RiCatmullRomBasis;
RI_EXPORT void    RiBasis(RtBasis u);
```

I want to retrieve the variable and function from the DLL and use them in my C++ code. When I do the following:

```
// Get the function.
void (*RiBasis)(RtBasis);
RiBasis = (void (*)(RtBasis))GetProcAddress(h, "RiBasis");

// Get the variable.
RtBasis *RiCatmullRomBasis;
RiCatmullRomBasis = (RtBasis*)GetProcAddress(h, "RiCatmullRomBasis");

// Call the function, passing it the variable.
RiBasis(RiCatmullRomBasis);
```

Visual C++ gives this compile error on the call to RiBasis:

```
error C2664: 'void (float [][4])': cannot convert argument 1
from 'RtBasis (*)' to 'float [][4]'
```

I tried removing one level of indirection from the RiCatmullRomBasis variable:

```
// Get the variable.
RtBasis RiCatmullRomBasis;
RiCatmullRomBasis = (RtBasis)GetProcAddress(h, "RiCatmullRomBasis");

// Call the function, passing it the variable.
RiBasis(RiCatmullRomBasis);
```

but that gave me the following on the GetProcAddress call:

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'FARPROC' to 'RtBasis'
note: There are no conversions to array types, although there are
conversions to references or pointers to arrays
```

What's the correct way of declaring the types in my C++ code to make this work?

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361479/how-to-pass-parameters-to-dll/27361835#27361835).  Why are you casting the address of a function pointer to a two dimensional array of `float`?

Comment: once you LoadLibray, the global variable should be accessible in your code, but you do GetProcAddress on the variable even though it is not a function. have you tried just declaring an `extern "C" RtBasis RiCatmullRomBasis;` in your code and then try to access it?

Comment: According to the docs, GetProcAddress() is also used to return the addresses of exported variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version make the call as:

```
RiBasis(*RiCatmullRomBasis);
```

You need to get the address of the variable (that is what GetProcAddress can return), but the function takes an instance rather than a pointer so you have to dereference the returned pointer.